# fcm not arrive the data to samsung device

Tags: php, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am testing FCM  in android but in samsung device not receive notification.

The code in php I send for testing.

**PROBLEM :  When remove the field notification
not arrive the notification  to device Samsung not send data**

### I hope you help me

```php
<?php
  Replace with the real server API key from Google APIs
     $apiKey = "xxxxxxx";

  Replace with the real client registration IDs
  $registrationIDs = array( "xxxxx")

 $fields = array(
      'priority' => 'high',

      'registration_ids' => $registrationIDs,

this line => 'notification' => array("priority"=>'high',
                        "content_available" => true,
                        "mutable_content" => true,
                        'priority'=>'high',
                        "title" => $message, 
                        "body" => $nickname ." Posteo una Inspección", 
                        "sound"=>"default",
                        "click_action"=> "OPEN_ACTIVITY_CHAT"),

              'data' => array(
                "title" => $message, 
                "body" => $nickname ." posteo una Inspección",
                "type" => "0",
                "content-available"=> "1","icon" > "ic_launcher"),
                );
  $headers = array(
      'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
      'Content-Type: application/json'
  );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the Android client code is correct? 
Have you tried sending yourself a message from the Firebase Console? 
https://console.firebase.google.com/

Are you using the correct `Server Key`?

> It should be the one found in the Firebase Console for your project 
>   On the top left, you should see `Project Overview`, click on the gear icon next to it. 
>   Now click on `Project Settings`. 
>   Then click on the `Cloud Messaging` tab.

Are you using the correct registration ID? 
Are you getting the registration ID that your device generates and then using it in PHP?

It might not be a problem with the PHP code, it might just be all the little details of setting it up. 
We will try to clear that up first and then dive into the PHP.

Comment: the notification work perfectly in  device motorola, but in any device samsung  NOT

Comment: When send without field notification the motorola receive notification

Comment: @Dverdugo Oh okay.

Comment: but when remove field notification the samsung device not arrive notification  with data information

Comment: because I show  the notification with reply!! I need change style